# Timer not stopping with other state changes in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, timer, setinterval

I am working on a simple quiz application in react native along with redux. I have a Quiz component (parent) and a Question component (child) in my app. When the user comes to the Quiz component, it renders the Question component based on the questions array which contains the data for the questions, and the Question component is updated with the next question whenever the user clicks on the Next button or the timer on the question finishes. When it's the last question, the next button changes into Finish button and when the Finish button is pressed, a modal is popped up displaying the user's score.

The problem I am facing is that when the user is on the last question and gives the correct answer and clicks the finish button, the modal is popped up but the timer doesn't stop until it reaches 1. Note that the timer stops if the user presses the finish button after giving the wrong answer or giving no answer at all. Please help me out regarding this. I have attached the code for the Quiz and the Question component.

Quiz Component

```js
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import Question from './Question';
import {quizQuestions} from './questions';
import {
  moveUserToFailed,
  moveUserToPassed,
  updateUserNumberOfAttempts,
  updateUserScore,
} from '../User/store/user.actions';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';

export default function Quiz(props: any) {
  const {navigation} = props;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const {users, selectedUser} = useSelector((state: any) => state.users);

  function shuffle(arr: Array<any>) {
    const array = [...arr];
    let currentIndex = array.length,
      randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle.
    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
      // Pick a remaining element.
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex--;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
        array[randomIndex],
        array[currentIndex],
      ];
    }

    return array;
  }

  const [questionNumber, setQuestionNumber] = useState<number>(0);

  const quizQuestionsShuffled = useMemo(() => {
    return shuffle(quizQuestions);
  }, []);

  const numberOfQuestions = useMemo(() => {
    return quizQuestionsShuffled.length;
  }, [quizQuestionsShuffled]);
  const currentQuestion = quizQuestionsShuffled[questionNumber];
  // console.log('currentQuestion', currentQuestion);

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const onNextQuestion = useCallback((): void => {
    setQuestionNumber(questionNumber + 1);
  }, [questionNumber]);

  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('');
  const incrementScore = useCallback(() => {
    if (currentQuestion && selectedOption === currentQuestion.answer) {
      setScore((previousScore: number) => previousScore + 1);
    }
  }, [currentQuestion, selectedOption]);

  const handleNext = useCallback(() => {
    incrementScore();
    onNextQuestion();
    setSelectedOption('');
    reset();
  }, [incrementScore, onNextQuestion]);

  const intervalRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const onFinish = useCallback(() => {
    stop();
    incrementScore();
    dispatch(updateUserScore({userId: selectedUser.userId, score: score}));
    const percentage = (score / numberOfQuestions) * 100;
    if (percentage >= 60) {
      dispatch(moveUserToPassed(selectedUser.userId));
    } else {
      dispatch(moveUserToFailed(selectedUser.userId));
    }
    dispatch(updateUserNumberOfAttempts(selectedUser.userId));
    setModalVisible(true);
  }, [dispatch, incrementScore, numberOfQuestions, selectedUser.userId, score]);

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(5);
  console.log(timer);

  const reset = () => {
    setTimer(5);
  };

  const start = useCallback(() => {
    setTimer(prev => {
      if (prev === 0) {
        stop();
        return 0;
      }
      return prev - 1;
    });
  }, []);

  const interval = useCallback(() => {
    //assign interval ref here
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      start();
    }, 1000);
  }, [start]);

  const stop = () => {
    //clear the interval ref
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    interval();

    if (timer === 0 && questionNumber === numberOfQuestions - 1) {
      onFinish();
      stop();
    } else if (timer === 0 && questionNumber < numberOfQuestions - 1) {
      handleNext();
    }

    return () => {
      stop();
    };
  }, [
    timer,
    onFinish,
    handleNext,
    questionNumber,
    numberOfQuestions,
    incrementScore,
    interval,
  ]);

  return (
    <Question
      questionNumber={questionNumber + 1}
      numberOfQuestions={numberOfQuestions}
      question={currentQuestion?.question}
      options={currentQuestion?.options}
      answer={currentQuestion?.answer}
      onNextQuestion={onNextQuestion}
      navigation={navigation}
      timer={timer}
      users={users}
      selectedOption={selectedOption}
      setSelectedOption={setSelectedOption}
      modalVisible={modalVisible}
      setModalVisible={setModalVisible}
      selectedUser={selectedUser}
      handleNext={handleNext}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      score={score}
    />
  );
}
```

Question Component

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Pressable,
  Modal,
} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {globalStyles} from '../../../globalStyles';
import {StackActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {quizQuestions} from '../questions';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

interface QuestionProps {
  question: string;
  options: string[];
  answer: string;
  questionNumber: number;
  numberOfQuestions: number;
  onNextQuestion: () => void;
  navigation: any;
  timer: number;
  users: any;
  selectedUser: any;
  selectedOption: string;
  setSelectedOption: any;
  modalVisible: boolean;
  setModalVisible: any;
  handleNext: any;
  onFinish: any;
  score: number;
}

export default function Question({
  question,
  options,
  questionNumber,
  numberOfQuestions,
  navigation,
  timer,
  users,
  selectedUser,
  selectedOption,
  setSelectedOption,
  modalVisible,
  setModalVisible,
  handleNext,
  onFinish,
  score,
}: QuestionProps) {
  const popAction = StackActions.pop(1);

  const selectedUserDetails = users.find(
    (user: any) => user.id === selectedUser.userId,
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.questionContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.timer}>{timer}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.questionNumber}>
          Question {questionNumber} of {numberOfQuestions}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.question}>{question}</Text>
        <View>
          {options.map((option: string) => (
            <Pressable
              key={option}
              style={
                selectedOption !== option
                  ? styles.option
                  : [styles.option, styles.selectedOption]
              }
              onPress={() => setSelectedOption(option)}>
              <Text style={styles.optionText}>{option}</Text>
            </Pressable>
          ))}
        </View>
      </View>
      {!(questionNumber === numberOfQuestions) ? (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.nextButton}
          onPress={() => handleNext()}
          // disabled={selectedOption === ''}
        >
          <Text style={styles.nextButtonText}>Next Question</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.nextButton}
          onPress={() => {
            onFinish();
          }}>
          <Text style={styles.nextButtonText}>Finish</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      <Modal
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <View>
              <Icon
                name={
                  selectedUserDetails.status === 'passed' ? 'check' : 'times'
                }
                size={100}
                color={
                  selectedUserDetails.status === 'passed'
                    ? globalStyles.green
                    : globalStyles.red
                }
              />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.modalStatus}>
              You {selectedUserDetails.status} the quiz!
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.modalScore}>
              Score {score} / {quizQuestions.length}
            </Text>
            <Pressable
              style={styles.modalButton}
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                navigation.dispatch(popAction);
              }}>
              <Text style={styles.modalButtonText}>OK</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: globalStyles.darkPurple,
    height: '100%',
    padding: 10,
  },
  questionContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  questionNumber: {
    color: globalStyles.purple,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 15,
  },
  question: {
    color: globalStyles.white,
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'center',
    height: 150,
    fontWeight: '700',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  option: {
    backgroundColor: globalStyles.white,
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  selectedOption: {
    borderWidth: 5,
    marginVertical: 5,
    borderColor: globalStyles.purple,
  },
  optionText: {
    color: globalStyles.darkPurple,
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  nextButton: {
    borderColor: globalStyles.white,
    borderWidth: 2,
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  nextButtonText: {
    color: globalStyles.white,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 22,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
  },
  modalView: {
    width: 350,
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  modalScore: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: globalStyles.purple,
  },
  modalButton: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: globalStyles.darkPurple,
    display: 'flex',
    width: 100,
  },
  modalButtonText: {
    color: globalStyles.white,
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  modalStatus: {
    fontSize: 26,
    marginBottom: 15,
    color: globalStyles.darkPurple,
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  timer: {
    color: globalStyles.white,
  },
});
```

I tried to place the `stop()` function in various places in my code.